# TFS 2017 How to query Work Items using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, tfs

I'm searching for a way to query work items directly from the SQL database of TFS using SQL selects.

For TFS 2010, there were some database views you could use to achieve this goal. [TFS2010: How to query Work Items using SQL on the Relational Warehouse](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/granth/2010/05/09/tfs2010-how-to-query-work-items-using-sql-on-the-relational-warehouse/)

The example from the WIQ looks like this:

```
SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State]
FROM WorkItems 
WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @project
  and [System.WorkItemType] = 'Ticket'
  and [System.State] <> 'Closed'
  and [System.State] <> 'Removed'
```

Comment: It is not recommended to connect to or query the TFS operational store directly. You should use the API. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MrHinsh I want to send a sms to a cellphone whenever the query from above returns at least one workitem. We have a monitoring software in our company [PRTG](https://www.de.paessler.com/snmp_monitor) to do so, but it doesn't have any kind of tfs sensor. The fastest way, i could think of, to get this information, is letting the PRTG query the TFS database.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way I've found so far is to use the database view `vw_denorm_WorkItemCoreLatest`. In this case "Latest" means, you only get the latest revision of the workitem without any previous versions of it. If you need all versions of a workitem, use the view `vw_WorkItemCoreAll`.

Except the selected columns, this is as close as I got to the WIQ from my question:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[vw_denorm_WorkItemCoreLatest]
WHERE [System.TeamProject] = 'MyTeamProject'
  and [System.WorkItemType] = 'Ticket'
  and [System.State] <> 'Closed'
  and [System.State] <> 'Removed'
```

Comment: At least write a comment why you downvote - the query works and does exactly what i needed.